# Function with Taylor series of order $k,$ which is not twice differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that it has order $k$ Taylor expansion at $0$ but $f"(0)$ does not exist.

It is a problem I am dealing with and for which I can't find any example. I would appreciate if someone could give me any example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Quite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) [often](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html), the Taylor expansion is in fact **defined** in terms of the derivatives at the point of expansion, so it seems you have s different definition? (Something like: a polynomial such that the error is $o(x^k)$?)

Comment: Perhaps you mean $k=1$ because if $f''(0)$ does not exist then there is no way you can have a Taylor series of order $2$ or more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing. If $f$ has derivatives up to order $n\geq0$ at $0$ then the $n^{\rm th}$ order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$ is given by
$$j^n_0f\,(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n{f^{(k)}(0)\over k!}\>x^k\ ,$$
period. One then can deliberate how well this polynomial approximates $f$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

If $f''(0)$ does not exist then there is no second order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed OP meant there exists $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k$ such that around $0$, $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_kx^k+o(x^k)$ but $f''(0)$ does not exist.
**Hint** :
For $k=2$ consider : $$\begin{align}f:&\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\&x\mapsto 0\text{ if } x=0\\&x\mapsto x^3\sin(x^{-1}) \text{ if } x\neq0 \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see that it does not have second derivative but.. How would you see that it does have order k Taylor expansion? I mean, what do you mean by k=2? Just, f(0)+another term? Or f(0)+2 more terms?

Comment: You can show that $f(x)=o(x^2)$

Comment: Oh, sorry i was editing my comment and i saw you just answered

Comment: @Jennifer: Nice function example, it is also easy to see what difference it would make to allow negative exponents in the expansion (combining sin's expansion with $x^{-1}$ geometric expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability is a **local** property. The key question will be **where** is it not twice differentiable. Taylor series and more generally Laurent series will be expandable with convergence radius up to it's closest pole. For example the function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}$$

Will be Taylor expandable around $x=0$ with convergence radius $\min\{|0-(-1)|,|0-1|\} = 1$. We won't be able to calculate second derivative at $\pm1$, so we would fail if we tried centering the expansion around any of those two points.

Even if the pole of a function is right on the point we want to expand around the we can still find a **Laurent expansion**, that is a power series allowing negative integer exponents:

$$f(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_kx^k$$

But with only positive exponents as the Taylor expansion has, it would not be possible.